# Fixed inner divs on scrollable outer

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have some page content in a React web app where certain fields should remain fixed as the user scrolls. The part that's throwing me off is this content is contained within a scrollable outer div. That outer div must remain scrollable because it occasionally loads different components that need it.

Here is the div structure:

```
<div class="inner"><!-- overflow-y: auto; (this must remain)-->

  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="titleBar"> <!-- I need this to not scroll -->
      <div class="mainTable">
        <table>
          <th>...</th> <!-- I need this to not scroll -->
          <tbody>
            ...
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

So as the user scrolls down the page, the title bar and table header should remain fixed, with the table body content being the only thing on the page that is scrolling. I'm not able to just make the table body scrollable because that will put a scrollbar on the table itself, it needs to scroll on the actual page scroll.

Most posts on this I've been able to find are using JQuery, but since this is within ReactJS I'm looking for other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Correct table head structure is:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Then try customize thead th css as following:

```
thead th {
  position:sticky;
  top: 0
}
```